# Virtual Method not calling dervied class method. - C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I have a method in both the base class and the derived class.  When I call this method on an object in the derived class it calls the base class method and not the derived class method.  Here is my code:

Person.h

```
class Person
{
...
public:
...
    virtual void coutPerson();
};
```

Person.cpp

```
void Person::coutPerson() {
    cout << name << endl;
    birthday.coutDate();
    phoneNumber.coutPhoneNumber();
    cout << city << ", " << state << endl;
}
```

Student.h

```
class Student : public Person
{
...
public:
...
    virtual void coutPerson();
};
```

Student.cpp

```
void Student::coutPerson() {
    cout << "DEBUG: Student::coutPerson()" << endl;
    //Person::coutPerson();
    cout << "Dorm Room: " << this->dorm << " " << this->dormRoom << endl;
}
```

Object created at: `addPerson<Student>(personVector);`
When object is created it is created as a Student because it calls the Student construtor.
Method called at: `personVector[num-1].coutPerson();`
The Student object is the one being told to coutPerson because it is displaying the info that I gave it when I created the Student object.

```
template<typename T> void addPerson(vector<Person> &personVector) {
    T p;
    personVector.push_back(p);
}
```

When the coutPerson() method is called on a Student object it only couts the name, birthday, phoneNumber, and city & state.  What is wrong with this code?  It should be calling the Student coutMethod...

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the call site? What syntax is used at the call site?

Comment: Make sure you are calling the method through a pointer or a reference, not through an actual object, unless the object is of type `Student`, _not_ of type `Person`

Comment: Could you please show the code calling `coutPerson()`? I'm pretty sure the problem is there.

Comment: What's `addPerson`? What's `personVector`?

Comment: The code calling coutPerson probably not the problem.  I create a Student with name studentName, ect... and it couts "studentName", ect... without the other Student specific values.

Comment: I'm betting that you slice your `Student` into a `Person` when adding it to the vector but you need to post something closer to a complete compilable example.

Comment: To add to celtschk.. add the construction of the object with that code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `personVector` contains `Person` objects. Not references to `Person` objects, but actual `Person` objects. When you "put your `Student` object into the vector", what really happens is that the vector constructs a *new* `Person` object, which is copy-initialized with the `Student` object you give to it, that is, it creates a *copy* of the `Person` part of the `Student` object. This behaviour is also known as "slicing".

Since there is no `Student` object in the vector, but only a `Person` object, it is no surprise that calling `coutPerson` on it calls `Person::coutPerson`, not `Student::coutPerson`.

If you want polymorphic behaviour, you have to store pointers (preferably smart pointers like `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`) in the container. Note however that the object `p` you constructed in your function is destroyed on return, so for the object to survive (so you can have a pointer to it) you have to allocate it with `new`.

Comment: Worked for me.
I had a BaseClass objects array (BaseClass*) with items being assigned to derived class object instances. So, even though my base class functions were virtual, and derived ones clearly overriding them, runtime polymorphism wasn't working. So had to change my BaseClass objects array to BaseClass object pointers array (BaseClass**) and defined the objects separately. I did have to care about the objects life cycle now in order to keep their references in the array valid. Some objects where defined using new, and others were assigned by using pointers to static derived objects.

Answer (score 9):

You are probably copying the `Student` object to a `Person` object at some point, leading to the [Object Slicing Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). For example you may be storing them in a `vector<Person>`. You need to use a pointer or reference instead of copying the object.

To explain why this is a problem, you must realize that a vector doesn't store the actual object you pass to it in `push_back`, it stores a *copy* of the object. When you copy a `Student` to a `Person`, the copy isn't a `Student` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The functions are fine. You're either calling `coutPerson` from an object of type `Person`, or calling it from inside `Person`'s constructor/destructor (thanks @celtschk).
You should be calling via a *pointer* or *reference* to an object of type `Person`. That's how you obtain polymorphism.

Comment: Or reference- crucial difference.

Comment: Nice but how do you know that?

Comment: I guess 9 out of 10 times without even seeing the code that this is the problem.

Comment: @Alex: Dunno, what else can it be?

Comment: @AssafLevy: Calling the function from the constructor or destructor of the base class.